# How Locale could be used in multithreaded application to improve performance

Tags: java, multithreading

In my application I have a method which is called by multiple threads simultaneously. Each thread calls this method many times while running.

```
private Locale trLoc = new Locale("tr", "TR");

public double calculate(String arg1){
    arg1 = arg1.toUpperCase(trLoc);
...
}
```

This method makes a `String.toUpperString(Locale)` call which causes a bottleneck because of the `HashTable` usage within the Locale class. Each thread waits other one while `toUpperCase` method operates. This situation slows down my application up to three times.

Is there something I'm missing with the usage of the Locale or I must use another class for the same purpose?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about using ICU4J ? https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/released/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/lang/UCharacter.html as a workaround ? The library is kind of heavy but well known for treating unicode correctly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After short exploring it looks like JDK can't help you. I suggest get `java.lang.ConditionalSpecialCasing` class, copy it and fix problem with Hashtable. You may replace `Hashtable` with `HashMap`. I do not see any reason for using `Hashtable` here.

Comment: I'm surprised that such a "feature" wasn't detected before. I did Google for performance issues related to `ConditionalSpecialCasing` and came up with nothing.

Comment: It happens only for (java.lang.String)
 `boolean localeDependent = (lang == "tr" || lang == "az" || lang == "lt");`

Comment: It would probably be worth reporting this [to Oracle](http://bugreport.java.com) - I'd do it, but I think it would be best if the RFE was filed by someone who has actually encountered the issue and can provide a test case.

Answer (score 5):

Edit: The solution bellow won't actually work, because the problematic `HashTable` in the `java.lang.ConditionalSpecialCasing` class is static and will still be shared by all threads. I suggest that you accept sibnick's answer instead of mine.

---

One simple solution would be to make trLoc a `ThreadLocal`: a new instance will be automatically created for each thread (as needed). This will work fine if you have a thread pool or similar: you will only create as many instances of `Locale` as you have threads in your pool, which should be quite reasonable. And since each thread will access a different instance of `Locale`, you will no longer have contention to access the synchronized HashTable.

```
private ThreadLocal<Locale> trLoc = new ThreadLocal<Locale>() {
    @Override
    protected Locale initialValue() {
        return new Locale("tr", "TR");
    }
};

public double calculate(String arg1){
    arg1 = arg1.toUpperCase(trLoc.get());
    ...
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. `ConditionalSpecialCasing` still uses the same `Hashtable` internally, no matter how many `Locale`s you create.

Comment: After checking the code, it definitely looks like you're right - the HashTable is static and will always be shared by all threads... I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the answer from [@sibnick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/159923/sibnick) I runned some a [JMH](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh) benchmark.

- `upperCaseEN` uses `Local.ENGLISH`
- `upperCaseTR` uses `new Locale("tr", "TR")`

## JDK 8

```
Benchmark                              Mode  Samples     Score  Score error   Units
s.o.MyBenchmark.upperCaseEN           thrpt       25  9680.129       89.485  ops/ms
s.o.MyBenchmark.upperCaseTR           thrpt       25   992.973        6.306  ops/ms
```

## JDK 8 patched

Using a patched `ConditionalSpecialCasing` class using `HashMap` instead of `Hashtable`

```
Benchmark                              Mode  Samples     Score  Score error   Units
s.o.MyBenchmark.upperCaseTR           thrpt       25  3331.277       77.691  ops/ms
```

Another solution could be to first scan the string if it contains a lowercase `i`. As this seems to be the only character which needs a special handling for `toUpperCase` in Turkish locale.

```
if (state.lowercase.contains("i")) {
    uppercase = lowercase.toUpperCase(TR_LOCALE));
} else {
    uppercase = lowercase.toUpperCase(EN_LOCALE));
}
```

Which improves the performance already.

```
Benchmark                              Mode  Samples     Score  Score error   Units
s.o.MyBenchmark.upperCasePatchedTR    thrpt       25  8753.116       51.582  ops/ms
```

**edit** The code for the benchmarks can be found at

https://github.com/SubOptimal/stackoverflow-answers/tree/master/question-31987777

Comment: Using the wrong locale if the string contains i or ï (that will be perhaps most of them) seems incorrect. (There's a similar  problem with Lithuanian and, I believe, surrogates.) I guess you could remove the problematic letters from unspecial ones, to upper case and then replace the letters.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline The question was about locale `tr_TR` and for this only the lower case `i` needs a special handling in the conversion to upper case. I edit my answer to make this explicit. You're right for a different locale (which involves `ConditionalSpecialCasing`) this needs some amendment.

Comment: (I've had a go at substituting the 'i's out. There's only a small performance improvement even with threads on my 2014 MacBook Air (motherboard from 2019...).)

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline I added a link to the source code used for the benchmarks.

Answer (score 0):

Building on SubOptimal's suggest of scanning for lowercase 'i', I have have tried a bit code to replace i with an innocuous character, to upper case, and the substituting back. My dodgy performance test does not show a great improvement in speed, YMMV. Do test performance with **JMH** instead, but you already knew that.

I then had a go at a table based approach. That is fast as expected.

As always, code for information only. Barely tested.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.*;

public class Benchmark {
    // Substitute i Turkish toUpperCase.
    public static String toUpperCase(String str) { 
        int index = str.indexOf('i');
        if (index == -1) {
            return str.toUpperCase(tr);
        } else {
            char[] array = str.toCharArray();
            char[] localised = toUpperCase(array, index);
            return String.valueOf(localised);
        }
    }
    private static char[] toUpperCase(char[] array, int index) {
        array[index] = 'X';
        int next = indexOf('i', array, index+1);
        final char[] localised;
        if (next == -1) {
            String upper = String.valueOf(array).toUpperCase(tr);
            int len = upper.length();
            if (len == array.length) {
                localised = array;
                upper.getChars(0, len, localised, 0);
            } else {
                localised = upper.toCharArray();
            }
        } else {
            localised = toUpperCase(array, next);
        }
        localised[index] = '\u0130';
        return localised;
    }
    private static int indexOf(char c, char[] array, int off) {
        while (off<array.length && array[off] != c) {
            ++off;
        }
        return off==array.length ? -1 : off;
    }

    // Table-based Turkish toUpperCase.

    private static final int limit = 1<<9;
    private static final char[] table;
    static {
        Locale locale = new Locale("tr", "TR");
        table = new char[limit];
        char[] buff = { ' ' };
        for (int c=0; c<limit; ++c) {
            buff[0] = (char)c;
            String upper = String.valueOf(buff).toUpperCase(locale);
            if (upper.length() != 1 && c != 223 && c != 329 && c != 496) { // es zett etc
                throw new Error("do not run: "+c);
            }
            table[c] = upper.charAt(0);
        }
    }

    public static String tableToUpperCase(String str) {
        int len = str.length();
        char[] buff = new char[len];
        int i;
        for (i=0; i<len; ++i) {
            char c = str.charAt(i);
            if (c >= limit || c == 223 || c == 329 || c == 496) {
                break;
            }
            buff[i] = table[c];
        }
        return i==len ? String.valueOf(buff) : str.toUpperCase(tr);
    }

    // Ropey benchmark.

    private static final Locale tr =
        new Locale("tr", "TR");
        //Locale.ENGLISH;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.err.println("friingi".toUpperCase(tr));
        System.err.println(toUpperCase("friingi"));
        int total = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<5; ++i) {
            long start = System.nanoTime();
            total += run();
            long time = System.nanoTime()-start;
            System.err.println(time/1000_000_000.0);
        }
        System.err.println(total);
    }
    private static int run() {
        AtomicInteger total = new AtomicInteger(0);
        List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0; i<100; ++i) {
           threads.add(new Thread(() -> { 
               total.addAndGet(runOne());
           }));
        }
        threads.forEach(Thread::start);
        threads.forEach(thread -> {
            try {
                thread.join();
            } catch (Exception exc) {
                throw new Error(exc);
            }
         });

        return total.get();
    }
    private static int runOne() {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<10_000; ++i) {
            sum +=
                /**/
                tableToUpperCase("fringe")
                //toUpperCase("fringe")
                /*/
                "fringe".toUpperCase(tr)
                /**/
                .length();
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```